# Activity not found

Tags: android, android-manifest

Deletei o `MainActivity` e criei 2 Layouts.

Um com nome de `activity_acessar` e `activity_menu`.

Porém quando vou executar exibe a seguinte mensagem.

> Error running app: Default Activity not found.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="org.view.activityAcessar" />
    <activity android:name="org.view.activityMenu"></activity>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa colocar o `intent-filter` dentro de sua `activity`. Veja:

```
<activity android:name="org.view.activityAcessar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

O `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` é o ponto de entrada do aplicativo, ou seja, quando você inicia o aplicativo, essa atividade é criada.

Você pode ver mais detalhes [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN).